# ValueError: too many values to unpack - kml creation

Tags: python, kml

from this lst

```
lst = [[234.0, 395795.57, 6689371.9], [235.0, 
  378397.16, 6558376.17], [236.0, 389841.36, 
  6643245.34]]

kml = simplekml.Kml(open=1)

single_point = kml.newpoint(name="The World", coords=[(0.0,0.0)])

for num, lat, lon in lst:
    pnt = kml.newpoint()
    pnt.name = boreCode
    pnt.coords = [(lon, lat)]

kml.save("kml_file.kml")
```

The error is now showing as:  `AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'count'` when i change the the firstcolumn values to integers it changes the 'float' to 'int' in the error message too

Comment: can u describle ur lst

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each list within the list `lst` contains 6 elements but unpacking only 3. You need to have something like

```
for num, lat, lon, x, y ,z in lst
```

Comment: i temorarily got rid of the last three columns in lst, to fix the last problem, thx. But now this error: `AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'count` happens. Do you have any idea what this could mean?

Comment: Can you share the code? This error means that you are trying access 'count' on a float object.

Comment: i have updated the above question, do you need the code where i created the list?

Comment: ahh i figured it out, `point.name = boreCode` (boreCode should be num in the above code) needs to refer to a string, as its a name not a value of any kind, pls disregard, thx for your help